# How to print input with php code

Tags: php, html, input, output

I just start learning php and html and I wanted to make something that gets input and print out the output with php code. However, with the code I have, it lets me input, but not printing anything when I click submit. Why?

```
<html>
<head><title>Noob</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //to check if the form was submitted
 $username= $_POST['username'];
 echo $username;
}
?>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 3):

In the below line in your code

```
<input type="submit" name="submit value="Submit" />
```

the word name = "submit does not have a closing double colon

Comment: Thanks for that!! However, after I enter my data and press submit, the page just refresh and not printing the data out. Why is that?

Comment: @Joefa Replace    <form action="" method="post"> with  <form action=". $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ." method="post">

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is missing a quotation mark on the line where you have

```
<input type="submit" name="submit value="Submit" />
```

it should be

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed the quotes in button name

```
<html>
<head><title>Noob</title></head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />// you missed here
</form>

<?php
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //to check if the form was submitted
 $username= $_POST['username'];
 echo $username;
}
?>

</body>
<html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a syntax error you have missed the double quotes name="submit"

```
    <?php
     if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { //to check if the form was submitted
    // For printing whole post data
     echo '<pre>'; print_r($_POST);
     $username= $_POST['username'];
     echo $username;
    }
    ?>
```

You  can also use var_dump for printing out.
Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

are you sure you run the page via php interpreter?
in local you can use xampp or wampp(product by windows)
in mac you can use mampp